# A python script to collect google search results

Tags: python

this is my script which takes a file containing google dorks and a search term, then searching the term + the dork

```
import sys
query = sys.argv[1]
a=open(sys.argv[2])
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")
for i in a:
    for j in search(query+" "+i, tld="com", num=10, stop=10, pause=5):
        print(j)
```

the problem is no matter how i increase the number of seconds it fails every time and gives me an error
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests

I tried to add a sleep function to wait more seconds but the same problem

```
import sys
import time
query = sys.argv[1]
a=open(sys.argv[2])
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")
for i in a:
    for j in search(query+" "+i, tld="com", num=10, stop=10, pause=5):
        time.sleep(10)
        print(j)
```